# How to change default output Formatting of Powershell to use Format-Table -autosize?

Tags: powershell, formatting, formattable

How can I enforce powershell to use

```
Format-Table -auto
```

as a default formatting when writing a returned array of objects to the console?
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

If you are OK calling the cmdlet every time and if you have at least PowerShell v3.0 then you can set a `$PSDefaultParameterValues` which you can read more about at [about_Parameters_Default_Values](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/hh847819.aspx).

The syntax that would satisfy your need would be:

> ```
> $PSDefaultParameterValues=@{"<CmdletName>:<ParameterName>"="<DefaultValue>"}
> ```

So we add in the switch by setting it to `$true`.

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"Format-Table:Autosize"=$true}
```

To remove this you would have to do it much the same as you would a hashtable element

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues.Remove("Format-Table:Autosize")
```

---

From the aforementioned article here is some pertinent information as to how to deal with these.

> $PSDefaultParameterValues is a preference variable, so it exists only in the session
>       in which it is set. It has no default value.
>
> To set $PSDefaultParameterValues, type the variable name and one or more key-value pairs
>       at the command line.
>
> If you type another $PSDefaultParameterValues command, its value replaces the original 
>       value. The original is not retained.
>
> To save $PSDefaultParameterValues for future sessions, add a $PSDefaultParameterValues
>       command to your Windows PowerShell profile. For more information, see about_Profiles.

---

Outside of that I am not sure as it would be difficult to change in a dynamic sense. You would want to be sure that data sent to the stream appears on screen in the same way that `format-table -auto` does but you would have to make sure that it does not affect data so that you could not capture it or send it down the pipe.

You are looking at creating custom output format files, [like Frode F. talks about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794056/how-to-change-default-output-formatting-of-powershell-to-use-format-table-autos/36794488?noredirect=1#comment61164391_36794488), then you would need to consider looking at [about_Format.ps1xml](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh847831.aspx) but you would need to configure this for *every* object that you would want to display this way.

FileSystem.format.ps1xml, for example, would govern the output from `Get-ChildItem`. `Format-Table` is more dynamic and I don't think you can say just use `Format-Table` in that file.

Comment: Very useful to have in a profile. Be aware that this only applies when piping to `Format-Table`. Ex. `Get-ChildItem` by itself will use the output-types formatdata, while `Get-ChildItem | Format-Table` would be autosized. If you need it to apply without piping to `Format-Table`, you would need to import custom FormatData xml for the specific types of objects.

Comment: @FrodeF. Good point. Looking at it again I think that what the OP wants is what you are describing.