# Setting Default Object formatting as a table

Tags: windows, powershell, formatting, powershell-3.0

I have been working on a PowerShell function to query WSUS and return the Computer Name, Update Group, LastSyncTime, and Needed/Failed Updates.

The function outputs the object

```
typename: Microsoft.UpdateServices.Internal.BaseApi.ComputerTarget
```

I added custom properties to this existing object, and just wanted to set what objects are displayed in the output. To set this, I used this block of code:

```
#Creating my object:
[void][reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration")
$wsus = [Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.AdminProxy]::getUpdateServer("mywsusserver.domain.local",$False)
$results = $wsus.SearchComputerTargets("search_string")

#add Custom Members
$results | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name ComputerName -Value FullDomainName
$results | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "Groups" -NotePropertyValue ($results.GetComputerTargetGroups() | where {$_.name -ne 'All Computers'}).name
$results | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "NeededUpdates" -NotePropertyValue ($objupdateinfo.downloadedcount + $objupdateinfo.notinstalledcount)
$results | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "FailedUpdates" -NotePropertyValue $objupdateinfo.failedcount         

#set the default display properties for my object
$defaultDisplayset = 'ComputerName','Groups','IPAddress','LastSyncTime','NeededUpdates','FailedUpdates'

$defaultDisplayPropertySet = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSPropertySet('DefaultDisplayPropertySet',[string[]]$defaultDisplaySet)

$PSStandardMembers = [System.Management.Automation.PSMemberInfo[]]@($defaultDisplayPropertySet)

$results | Add-Member MemberSet PSStandardMembers $PSStandardMembers
```

Credit for display property info: [this article](https://learn-powershell.net/2013/08/03/quick-hits-set-the-default-property-display-in-powershell-on-custom-objects/).

So the when I display the output of this code block, I get something like this:

```
PS C:\> $results


ComputerName  : Servername1
Groups        : Third Week
IPAddress     : 192.168.1.100
LastSyncTime  : 9/13/2017 2:19:51 AM
NeededUpdates : 15
FailedUpdates : 0

ComputerName  : Servername2
Groups        : Customer - Third Week
IPAddress     : 192.168.100.73
LastSyncTime  : 9/13/2017 2:44:34 AM
NeededUpdates : 7
FailedUpdates : 0

ComputerName  : Servername3
Groups        : Third Week
IPAddress     : 192.168.200.233
LastSyncTime  : 9/13/2017 2:09:23 AM
NeededUpdates : 6
FailedUpdates : 0
```

And what I want to display by default is this:

```
ComputerName Groups     IPAddress       LastSyncTime         NeededUpdates FailedUpdates
------------ ------     ---------       ------------         ------------- -------------
Servername1  Third Week 192.168.1.100   9/13/2017 2:19:51 AM            15             0
Servername2  Third Week 192.168.100.73  9/13/2017 2:44:34 AM             7             0
Servername3  Third Week 192.168.200.233 9/13/2017 2:09:23 AM             6             0
```

But the only way I've found to achieve it is by using:

```
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

I've already explored [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36794056/how-to-change-default-output-formatting-of-powershell-to-use-format-table-autos/36794488?noredirect=1#comment61164391_36794488), by I just want the output of THIS OBJECT to be a table without having to use `Format-Table` to achieve it.

Comment: I think you have to use a format.ps1xml file to achieve what you want https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml?view=powershell-5.1